# GroovyMock not working when used to test Java class with static method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

Groovy test does not create a mock for static class, when that class is used inside other Java class. Below is a code snippet that proves this

Java class under test:

```
public class JavaClass {
    public void method() { 
      ClassWithStaticMethod.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Java class with static method:

```
public class ClassWithStaticMethod { 
    public static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Static method called");
    } 
}
```

Groovy test that fails:

```
class JavaClassTest extends Specification {
  def 'test'() {
    given:
    GroovyMock(ClassWithStaticMethod, global: true)
    JavaClass javaClass = new JavaClass()

    when:
    javaClass.method()

    then:
    1 * ClassWithStaticMethod.doSomething() // <--- FAILS
  }
}
```

This fails with message:

```
Static method called <--- original method is called, it's not mocked

Too few invocations for:

1 * ClassWithStaticMethod.doSomething()   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None
```

So, static method is not mocked and the actual implementation is always called. Can anyone explain this behaviour? Any idea how to bypass this?

Java version: 1.7.0_79, Groovy version: 2.4.7, Spock version: 1.0-groovy-2.4, cgclib: 3.1

Answer (score 1):

## If java codes are compiled with groovyc

```
    def "foo"() {
      setup:
        // GroovyMock(ClassWithStaticMethod, global: true)
        GroovySpy(ClassWithStaticMethod, global: true)
        JavaClass javaClass = new JavaClass()

      when:
        javaClass.method()

      then:
        // 1 * ClassWithStaticMethod.doSomething()
        1 * ClassWithStaticMethod.doSomething() >> null
    }
```

## If java codes are compied with javac

1.prepare test code(this sample is MySpock.groovy)

```
// This Grabs are used for compile.
// These libraries must specifiy on class path when the file executs.
@Grapes([
  @Grab(group='org.jmockit', module='jmockit', version='1.8'),
  @Grab(group='org.spockframework', module='spock-core', version='1.0-groovy-2.4')
])

import spock.lang.*
import mockit.*

class MySpock extends Specification {

  def "hoge"() {
    setup:

    // Overwrite ClassWithStaticMethod#doSomething(static method) with JMockit/MockUp
    new MockUp<ClassWithStaticMethod>() {
      @Mock
      public static void doSomething() {
        Logger.append("abc")
      }

    }

    // Target object for this test
    JavaClass javaClass = new JavaClass()

    when: "Execute target method"
    javaClass.method()

    then: "ClassWithStaticMethod#doSomething was mocked and write the value in a file"
    Logger.count() == 1

    cleanup: "Delete log file for this test"
    Logger.delete()
  }
}

// Logging Utility for only this test.
class Logger {
  static logFile = new File("/tmp/MySpock.groovy.log")
  static append = {String msg -> logFile.append("${msg}${System.getProperty("line.separator")}")}
  static count = {logFile.readLines()?.size()?:0}
  static delete = { logFile.delete() }
}
```

2.compile codes

```
javac ClassWithStaticMethod.java&&javac JavaClass.java&&groovyc MySpock.groovy
```

3.execute test

```
groovy -cp .:$HOME/.groovy/grapes/org.jmockit/jmockit/jars/jmockit-1.8.jar:$HOME/.groovy/grapes/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-1.0-groovy-2.4.jar MySpock
```

I have used JMockit at first time.
So, I don't know whether this usage is correct.
I have no idea for method that access and add staic field each other between Spock and Mock(JMockit).
Therefore i created log file to check whether the "ClassWithStaticMethod#doSomething" is called from the "JavaClass#method".

Comment: oh yes. you are right...
I checked again.
The above code works if these codes(JavaClass.java and ClassWithStaticMethod.java) are compiled with "groovyc".

Comment: maybe it needs JMockit too for Mock of static method.